# Intersection point of two lines given starting points and ending points of both lines

Tags: geometry, intersection

I'm creating a program which requires me to get intersection point of two lines. I have tried using different formulas but none of them works perfectly for me. Following is one example which I found on math.stackexchange.

```
x = ((x1 - x2) * (u1 * v2 - u2 * v1) - (u2 - u1) * (x2 * y1 - x1 * y2)) / ((v1 - v2) * (x1 - x2) - (u2 - u1) * (y2 - y1))

y = (u1 * v2 * y1 - u1 * v2 * y2 - u2 * v1 * y1 + u2 * v1 * y2 - v1 * x1 * y2 + v1 * x2 * y1 + v2 * x1 * y2 - v2 * x2 * y1) / (-1 * u1 * y1 + u1 * y2 + u2 * y1 - u2 * y2 + v1 * x1 - v1 * x2 - v2 * x1 + v2 * x2)
```

given these points
A = (0.0, 0.0), B = (0.0, 50.0),
C = (20, 0), D = (70.0, 50)
my lines are AB and CD.
There is no intersection between above two lines. with above method it gives me following answer:
(0.0, -20.0).
Do you know of some method that makes sure that the line is not extended to infinity?

Comment: You are looking for the intersection between line *segments*, rather than between (infinite) lines. See eg [How do you detect where two line segments intersect?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/563198) and ["Intersections" on Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Line_segment_intersection).

Comment: @MarcoB Thanks Sir! That helped alot. I tried restricting the program to look for points only between the given line and it gave me correct result.

Answer (score 4):

```
a = {0.0, 0.0}; b = {0.0, 50.0};
c = {20, 0}; d = {70.0, 50};
ab = Line[{a, b}]; cd = Line[{c, d}];
RegionIntersection[{ab, cd}]

(* Out: EmptyRegion[2] *)
```

Answer (score 3):

```
$Version

(* "13.2.1 for Mac OS X ARM (64-bit) (January 27, 2023)" *)

Clear["Global`*"]
```

To avoid conflict with built-in symbol names, do not use capital letters for (or to start) user-defined symbols. For example `C` and `D` have pre-defined meanings.

```
a = {0, 0}; b = {0, 50}; c = {20, 0}; d = {70, 50};
```

For infinite lines,

```
lineABinf = InfiniteLine[{a, b}];
lineCDinf = InfiniteLine[{c, d}];
```

The infinite lines intersect at

```
pt = RegionIntersection[lineABinf, lineCDinf]

(* Point[{0, -20}] *)
```

For finite lines,

```
lineAB = Line[{a, b}];
lineCD = Line[{c, d}];

RegionIntersection[lineAB, lineCD]

(* EmptyRegion[2] *)
```

Graphically,

```
Graphics[{
  Text["A", a, {-2, 0}],
  Text["B", b, {-2, 0}],
  Text["C", c, {-2, 1}],
  Text["D", d, {-2, 1}],
  Text["pt", pt[[1]], {-2, 1}],
  Dashed,
  Lighter[Blue], lineABinf,
  Green, lineCDinf,
  Dashing[{}],
  Darker[Blue], lineAB,
  Darker[Green], lineCD,
  Red, AbsolutePointSize[6], pt},
 Frame -> True,
 PlotRange -> {{-5, 75}, {-25, 55}}]
```

[image]